# adding to two dictionaries together and the value are appended as list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this:

```
dict1 = {"a":3, 'b':4}
dict2 = {"a":6, 'b':5}
```

I need to get to this:

```
target_dict = {"a":[3,6], 'b':[4,5]}
```

I tried and it doesn't work.

```
from collections import defaultdict
target_dict  = defaultdict(list)
dict1 = {"a": [3], 'b':[4]}
dict2 = {"a": [6], 'b':[5]}
target_dict.append(dict1)
target_dict.append(dict2)
target_dict
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```py
from collections import defaultdict

dict1 = {"a": 3, 'b': 4}
dict2 = {"a": 6, 'b': 5}

target_dict = defaultdict(list)
for dictionary in [dict1, dict2]:
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        target_dict[k].append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help:

```
dict1 = {"a":3, 'b':4}
dict2 = {"a":6, 'b':5}

def combine(dict1,dict2):
    new_dict = {}
    for name in dict1.keys():
        new_dict[name]=[dict1[name],dict2[name]]
    return new_dict
```

And the result is `{'a': [3, 6], 'b': [4, 5]}`